# Can you make a method part of the default setter action in a property variable?

Tags: c#, properties, setter

If you have multiple properties that implement the same method in the setter, is there a way to make it part of the default setter?

If I have multiple properties that call a `Filter()` when they are set, is there a way to push it into a "base setter" so that I don't have to have the `Filter()` call in every setter?

```
private string _MyVal1;
public string MyVal1 {
    get {
        return _MyVal1;
    }
    set {
        _MyVal1 = value;
        Filter();
        OnPropertyChanged("MyVal1");
    }
}

private string _MyVal2;
public string MyVal2 {
    get {
        return _MyVal2;
    }
    set {
        _MyVal2 = value;
        Filter();
        OnPropertyChanged("MyVal2");
    }
}

private string _MyValN;
public string MyValN {
    get {
        return _MyValN;
    }
    set {
        _MyValN = value;
        Filter();
        OnPropertyChanged("MyValN");
    }
}
```

So it turns into this:

```
private string _MyValN;
public string MyValN {
    get {
        return _MyValN;
    }
    set : FilterSetter {
        _MyValN = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("MyValN");
    }
}
```

Comment: No, there is no way to do this.

Comment: So I'll have to put `Filter()` into every setter? Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: @Bob.: A better way? No, not really.

Comment: Yes, and, no. Sorry. You could merge Filter and OnPropertyChanged into one method, but that's about all.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Does that mean I can't enforce a method call inside a setter either? Unless I put it into the `OnPropertyChanged` method.

Comment: Or create a `IWishThisWereTheDefaultSetter(string propertyName)` method. Yes, that's right.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: see my interception example below. I see this as being a better way.

Comment: @Bob. You can use my interception example to even have it call the OnPropertyChanged for you since you know what the property name is. That is, a setter is a method called set_<propertyName> so it is easy to parse out the property name and called the property changed method with it. Just make sure the OnPropertyChanged method is in your class interface (or have you interface inherit from INotifypropertyChanged) so you can either call the method like i did with Filter, or so that you can invoke the event directly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A different way of doing this is to use interception like that provided by the Unity framework. With interception your class implements an interface and you would tell the framework that everytime a method is called on classes implementing that interface, run these interceptors. Your interceptors code can look to see if the method being called is prefixed with set_. Interceptor code executes once on the way to the function and once on the way back. On the way back, you can then have the interceptor call the filter method (assuming it is defined on the interface of course).

Concrete example:

### Get Prerequisite Library

Use NuGet to add Unity and Unity extensions to your project

### Define your interface to be intercepted: SomeObject.cs

```
using System;

namespace InterceptSetter
{
    interface ISomeObject
    {
        string SomeProperty { get; set; }
        void Filter();
    }

    public class SomeObject : ISomeObject
    {
        public string SomeProperty { get; set; }

        public void Filter()
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine("Filter Called");
        }
    }
}
```

### Define your Interception Behavior: SetterCallsFilterMethodBehavior.cs

```
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity.InterceptionExtension;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace InterceptSetter
{
    /// <summary>
    /// See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660871(v=pandp.20).aspx
    /// See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647107.aspx
    /// </summary>
    class SetterCallsFilterMethodBehavior : IInterceptionBehavior
    {
        public IEnumerable<Type> GetRequiredInterfaces()
        {
            // we dont need anything
            return new[] { typeof(ISomeObject) };
        }

        public IMethodReturn Invoke(IMethodInvocation input, GetNextInterceptionBehaviorDelegate getNext)
        { // Do not intercept non-setter methods
            if (!input.MethodBase.Name.StartsWith("set_"))
                return getNext()(input, getNext);

            IMethodReturn msg = getNext()(input, getNext);

            // post processing. this is where we call filter
            if (input.Target is ISomeObject)
            {
                (input.Target as ISomeObject).Filter();
            }

            return msg;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// We always execute
        /// </summary>
        public bool WillExecute
        {
            get { return true; }
        }
    }
}
```

### Write a test console program: Program.cs

```
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity.InterceptionExtension;
using System;

namespace InterceptSetter
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            UnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();

            container.AddNewExtension<Interception>();
            container.RegisterType<ISomeObject, SomeObject>(
                      new Interceptor<TransparentProxyInterceptor>(),
                      new InterceptionBehavior<SetterCallsFilterMethodBehavior>());

            // we must get our instance from unity for interception to occur
            ISomeObject myObject = container.Resolve<ISomeObject>();
            myObject.SomeProperty = "Hello Setter";

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Running this you will see that the interceptor does in fact call the filter method (which prints to the console).

Unity is not the only dependency injection / interception framework out there (google PostSharp). Unity is the one i am familiar with so thats what this example uses.

### Sources / See Also:

1. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660871(v=pandp.20).aspx  - Good diagram depicting the flow of interception
2. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647107.aspx - overkill of detail showing different interception techniques

Comment: Does this work if `Filter()` is abstract? That seems like a lot of work if I have many properties.

Comment: @Bob.: I admit, interception is a bit of setup but then filter and any other calls you want to always happen will happen automatically for all of your properties which is convenient and prevents bugs in case you forget to put it on a setter. As far as abstract methods go, it should be fine since the target of the setter is a completely concrete version of the class right? If you make your classes implement an interface, like my example does, you wont have to worry since that method will be required of the interface.

Comment: This seems a bit overkill. It would be better if you could just write something like "public int MyValue{get;set;}:SomeFunction()"

Answer (score 3):

You can create generic setter method and call that from each property setter:

```
private void Set<T>(ref T field, T value, string propertyName)
{
    field = value;
    Filter();
    OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
}
```

Then your properties look like:

```
public string SomeProperty
{
    get { return this.someField; }
    set
    {
        Set(ref this.someField, value, "SomeProperty");
    }
}
```