# Abstraction of class property creation in C#

Tags: c#

Consider following piece of code:

```
public class Foo
{
  private float propA = 1.0f;
  public float PropA 
  {
     get { return propA; }
     set { if (value != propA) { propA = value; DoBar(); } }
  }

  private int propB = 2;
  public int PropB 
  {
     get { return propB; }
     set { if (value != propB) { propB = value; DoBar(); } }
  }

  private double propC = -1.0;
  public double PropB 
  {
     get { return propC; }
     set { if (value != propC) { propC = value; DoBar(); } }
  }

  void DoBar() 
  {  
     //...Something is going on here
  }
}
```

I was wondering, if someone could recommend a nicer way for creating properties in C# lang? 
For instance in C++ i would use `MACRO` for this purpose, since it will allow me not only do some action when property has changed, but also reduce the repetition of boilerplate code.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged - then have your `OnPropertyChanged` method call `DoBar`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15228000/34092 is another approach to consider (similar to @SteveTodd's idea).

Comment: I would define an snippet for this. I have one that creates me the scaffolding for a property with change notification. I just type `mvvmprop` and done. [More info](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22658/Snippet-to-Generate-a-Public-Property-Private-Back)

Comment: Consider also [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-2795.SnippetDesigner) extension

Comment: After typing your snippet you would only need to set its name once (with a rule you can set private field name based on the property name), and its default value

Comment: Wow @taquion this looks really nice. Exactly what I was searching for. Thank you a lot!

Comment: Happy coding =)

Comment: @Zohar Peled, what does this question has to do with `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface? _since it will allow me not only do some action when property has changed_, this does not mean that the OP is using that interface....

Comment: @taquion I agree it's not the same question but the same solution applies to both.

Comment: and by the way @taquion if you would post your answer, I'll definitely accept it.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I don't agree, `taquion` solution to the problem is way more elegant and totally unrelated to INotifyPropertyChanged theme

Comment: @LeonidLazaryev doesn't matter! the important thing is that the problem is solved! =)

Comment: @LeonidLazaryev well, vote to reopen, then. I'm still not convinced I'm wrong in closing this as a duplicate - so I will not reopen it, but if 5 reopen votes or just 1 reopen vote from a c# gold badge holder will reopen it there's nothing I can do about it.

Comment: @ZoharPeled question bookmarked, in a couple of years (or more) when I am gold badge holder I will vote for reopen it =)

Comment: @ZoharPeled I've got my answer. Just wanted to accept an answer from `taquion`, other then that - I've got great solution already.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
   public class Foo
   {
      private float propA = 1.0f;
      public float PropA
      {
         get => propA;
         set => CheckAndExecute(ref propA, value);
      }

      private int propB = 2;
      public int PropB
      {
         get => propB;
         set => CheckAndExecute(ref propB, value);
      }

      private double propC = -1.0;
      public double PropC
      {
         get => propC;
         set => CheckAndExecute(ref propC, value);
      }

      private void CheckAndExecute<T>(ref T oldVal, T newVal) where T : IEquatable<T>
      {
         if (((IEquatable<T>) oldVal).Equals(newVal)) return;
         oldVal = newVal;
         DoBar();
      }

      void DoBar()
      {
         //...Something is going on here
      }
   }
```

You do the repeated work in a generic.

Comment: This is nice in terms of the equality check and the `DoBar` - but it doesn't remove the need to create the backing fields etc.

Comment: as @mjwills pointed out, it doesn't solve the problem of property creationbacking fields. But thank you for your opinion.

Comment: I don't think you can do away with the need for backing fields. Auto properties (which don't have backing fields) lack the ability to add code to their accessors.

Comment: @SteveTodd Have a read about Fody (see my earlier link).